# SQL count sum and joining table

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I ran into a question from my SQL class but did not have a solution to it.  My query needs to show ONLY the movies that have same number of female and male actors.

I have three tables:
(table:field 1,field2):

```
Casting: actor_number, movie_number
Actor_List: id, name, gender
Movie_List: id, movie_name
```

Comment: and have you tried anything ?

Comment: If you just get a solution here, how will you then learn? Create tables, add data and try different SQL constructions!

Comment: You need to investigate the JOIN clause in SQL.

Comment: I tried the count() and join clause by themselves; I don't really know how to nest them together to make this work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub-query uses a little CASE() trick to increment counts conditionally (i.e.  `countif`).  The sub-query factoring syntax means we only execute the query once.

```
with cte as (
    select m.movie_name
           , sum(case when a.gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as male_tot 
           , sum(case when a.gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as female_tot 
    from casting c
         join movie_list m
          on c.movie_number = m.id
         join actor_list a
          on c.actor_number = a.id
   group by m.name
    )
select cte.* 
from cte
where cte.male_tot = cte.female_tot ;
```